# Running script without virtualenv activation

Tags: python, virtualenv

Is there a difference between running script using virtualenv interpreter (without virtualenv activation) and running it in activated virtualenv?

```
venv/bin/python some_script.py
```

vs

```
source venv/bin/activate
python some_script.py
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running `source bin/activate` will set the PATH variable to point to your environment `bin` directory which is useful if you have other command line scripts/binaries installed (this can happen with certain python packages that add shell commands), it will also unset/set PYTHONHOME.

So, if `bin/python` works for you then you're fine but if some of the packages you're using start behaving strangely (or wrong one gets imported) it's probably because Python is getting the wrong PYTHONHOME or because a certain script is not found in PATH.

Comment: activate script modifies PATH, but I don't see it setting PYTHONHOME (ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Actually, it looks like it unsets PYTHONHOME. Maybe it's set somewhere else? Eitherway, there is definite PYTHONHOME handling in the activate script, it makes a copy of it and unsets it during activation and then sets it back during deactivation. Lines 13-17 and 49-55.

Comment: Does this mean that it's not possible to run a script without activating an environment?

Answer (score 8):

> If you directly run a script or the python interpreter from the virtualenv’s bin/ directory (e.g. path/to/ENV/bin/pip or /path/to/ENV/bin/python-script.py) then sys.path will automatically be set to use the Python libraries associated with the virtualenv. But, unlike the activation scripts, the environment variables PATH and VIRTUAL_ENV will not be modified. This means that if your Python script uses e.g. subprocess to run another Python script (e.g. via a #!/usr/bin/env python shebang line) the second script may not be executed with the same Python binary as the first nor have the same libraries available to it. To avoid this happening your first script will need to modify the environment variables in the same manner as the activation scripts, before the second script is executed.

source: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/16.7.9/userguide.html#activate-script

Comment: This is unbelievably stupid. Why did they design it this way? It's easier if I just clone the main installation rather than try to deal with this mess :\

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Virtualenv creates an interpreter in its own right. Just do this,

```
which python
```

For each interpreter, `virtualenv` and your normal interpreter and see what happens. They will show you two different links to python interpreter. Here's my example:

```
quazinafiulislam@Nafiuls-Mac: ~/Code/Python/PyTestingZone
 $ which python                                                                                               [7:49:26]
/Users/quazinafiulislam/.pyenv/shims/python

quazinafiulislam@Nafiuls-Mac: ~/Code/Python/PyTestingZone
 $ source .venv/bin/activate                                                                                  [7:49:29]
(.venv)
quazinafiulislam@Nafiuls-Mac: ~/Code/Python/PyTestingZone
 $ which python                                                                                               [7:49:35]
/Users/quazinafiulislam/Code/Python/PyTestingZone/.venv/bin/python
```