# VS Code task and Python virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a python virtual environment declared in my workspace settings, everything is fine with it.

Now I have a build task that calls a `make` target which in turn calls a pip package. When I run it, it doesn't use my `venv` even though it is the selected interpreter.

I've tried to add a `activate venv/...` before calling my `make` command but I get a `Permission denied` error in the embedded terminal.

How can I use a virtual environment and tasks at the same time?

Comment: Put python absolute path in your task. For instance: "command": "~/.pyenvs/myenv/bin/python myscript.py"

Comment: That's a good point but I should make it clearer that I'm calling a `make `target that calls my python script. I'll edit my message now. Any idea?

Comment: I have filed https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20054 - upvote if you find it useful.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I tested with the following tasks.json and it works:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "test",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "source /home/me/.pyenvs/myenv/bin/activate; make"
    }
  ]
}
```

First activate virtual environment and then executes make.

Comment: I was doing a similar thing with `source... & make` instead of `&&`.... Typos, typos, typos. I guess a `;` limits potential typos :) Thanks.

Comment: Any way not hardcoding the environment, but instead using the environment belonging to the Python interpreter currently selected in the VS Code GUI?

Comment: Yeah this works, but suddenly your tasks.json is not portable, and if you have many targets in your tasks.json you have to duplicate for each (so if path to venv changes that's a maintenance headache). I use an env var to set the path to my venv relative to my home directory & refer to that which helps with the duplication.  Gist showing this: https://gist.github.com/pzelnip/6265212ad8190e2202d7474f05f7384a  Still not portable though (if I move to a different machine & my venv is in a different path then I have to tweak my tasks.json).

Answer (score 32):

## Updated Answer

Since `"python.pythonPath"` was [deprecated in 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-may-2020-release/), you need to use `"${command:python.interpreterPath}"` instead in the **command** field.

## Old Answer

It might be a little late to answer your question but the trick is to set the command field to point to the **virtual environment's python executable** instead of the default `python`. If you set up your `.vscode`'s `settings.json` correctly you should have something like this in your file:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "env\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    // other settings ...
}
```

Having this config in your workspace, you can then create a custom task of type `process` using `${config:python.pythonPath}` as it's **command** field.

---

You can read all about it in [this section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution) of VSCode's docs.

This example creates a Django `python manage.py migrate` task:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Migrate",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "${command:python.interpreterPath}",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/manage.py",
                "migrate"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": false,
                "panel": "shared",
                "showReuseMessage": true,
                "clear": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer because of the interpolation of the current `python.PythonPath`. With this solution, if that path changes, you won't have to upgrade your task.

Frankly, I think it's a bit of a glaring feature omission in VSCode that you can't somehow specify a "python" type of task that uses your selected Python interpreter to run the command by default. This design suggests that build task commands can should only be globally installed, not per-project installed.

Comment: I needed to run this exact `migrate` command. But it still failed with Anaconda environment. So I've written a little more complicated command, which activates environment before running Python script: `${config:python.pythonPath}\\..\\..\\..\\Scripts\\activate ${config:python.pythonPath}\\.. && python manage.py migrate --noinput`

Comment: This answer is wrong and will lead to weird errors as can be read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70151208/5395110. It omits the activation which will work most of the times, but will fail in basically impossible to debug edge-cases.

Comment: Do we need to reset the site-pkgs dir, python path, etc. as well? (On linux, sorry)I would use `sudo -u`. Ive looked at the activate script before. on linux, it is just a sh script that more or less caters to the current $USER, so setting that to your username or uid _may_ work as well. For Windows, just open up the venv/bin/activate script and read it.

Comment: @t-mart Using a different executable wont change the ${PYTHON_PATH} will it? I was under the impression that all of the properties in the `sys` module were run via environment variables. Is that not the case, or is it os specific? Upvoted comment due to the second part.

Answer (score 7):

I had quite a lot of trouble with this recently myself. I wanted to update package requirements before running code, but I didn't want to implement a complex or maintenance-heavy solution. The following works well for me across Windows, OSX, and Linux environments.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "pipInstall",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${command:python.interpreterPath}",
      "args": ["-m", "pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I believe `${command:python.interpreterPath}` points to whatever interpreter path one selects while setting up the environment.

Comment: This seems to be the correct variable to use to find the python interpreter

Comment: This installs packages in the environment. How does it help *activate* environment before a task?

Comment: @bers The var `${command:python.interpreterPath}` should be pointing to the Python interpreter inside the created virtual environment. The other solutions here were doing the same thing except directly using the path. This simply uses VSCode's built-in functionality.

Comment: But the question is not about invoking the Python interpreter, but activating the venv.

Comment: To be clear, `${command:python.interpreterPath}` can be helpful in some situations, where you fully control the make file and can replace all Python script invocations (`module`) with `${command:python.interpreterPath} -m module`. But that is not always possible. And unless you activate the environment, a call to `pytest` (for instance) will not be using the right environment.

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237792/vs-code-task-and-python-virtual-environment/70456194?noredirect=1#comment85524775_49237792

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the shell in `tasks.json` in a way that works for `bash` and `cmd` shells. This worked for me and it correctly prints the full path to the python executable in the virutal environment.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "linux": {
        "options": {
            "shell": {
                "executable": "bash",
                "args": [
                    "--init-file",
                    "env/bin/activate",
                    "-ci",
                ]
            }
        },
    },
    "windows": {
        "options": {
            "shell": {
                "executable": "cmd.exe",
                "args": [
                    "/C",
                    "env\\Scripts\\activate.bat",
                    "&"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "test shell with virtualenv",
            "command": "which python", // where on Windows for testing
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This answer is the best one by far. Only improvement I see is to replace the `env` path in the shell args with a `${config:python.pythonPath}/../activate` and the respective Windows counterpart. That makes it conform to the selected venv in VSCode (except if you select the system interpreter, which does not have an activate script)

Comment: For multi root workspace, use `${workspaceFolder:sibling_dir}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but this alternative might be useful. If you use pipenv in stead of standard venv, you can use `pipenv run`. It will activate the virtualenv before running the process. For example, this works for building sphinx:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build html",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "pipenv",
            "args": [
                "run", 
                "sphinx-build", 
                "-b", 
                "html", 
                "${workspaceFolder}", 
                "${workspaceFolder}/_build/html"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing soon after my post, thanks for sharing!
I would recommend using [poetry](https://poetry.eustace.io/) instead of pipenv.

Answer (score 0):

For people who maybe using Poetry a solution is to run

poetry shell

before running VSCode but a better solution is to do the following. This has been mentioned in an earlier answer but not specifically for poetry.

[Use Poetry for Python Dependency](https://crapts.org/2020/05/11/use-poetry-for-python-dependency-management-with-visual-studio-code/)

Comment: Wouldn't this presume that poetry is installed globally? Like if you install Poetry into your venv, then this won't work since the venv isn't activated.