# vscode sphinx-build task in virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, python-sphinx

I am using virtualenv in vscode and I'd like to have a task to build the documentation using `sphinx-build`.
My tasks.json contains

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Build Docs",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "sphinx-build",
        "args": ["./sphinx", "./docs/sphinx_build"],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    }
```

However, when I run this it seems that vscode is not using the `Scripts` folder of my virtual environment, so I get

```
sphinx-build : The term 'sphinx-build' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

The same command runs just fine in the terminal. 
Am I missing something here? Is there a way to correctly point the task to the correct location in a virtual environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code task and Python virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56067344/962190)

Comment: Unfortunately no, because the command I'm running is `sphinx-apidoc`, and `${config:python.pythonPath}` points to the python executable.

Comment: I see. the other answer in that post suggests activating the virtualenv before calling the command that relies on the install. Does that work?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (I've just started using virtual environments), but that may be a feature of pipenv only. If possible I'd like to not disrupt my project too much. I must admit that vscode has spoiled me...I thought this would be easier with it having the virtualenv support built-in.

Comment: no, [any virtualenv can be activated](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#activate-script), and needing to do that is the price of environment insolation. I don't use vscode so I don't know how it wants to be used, but you could also set your `PATH` environment variable to include `your/virtualenv/location/bin`, since that `bin` is where the cli entrypoints like `sphinx-build` are installed into.

Comment: I moved my code over to Python 3.7 (in order to be able to use type hint comments with sphinx) and the builds seem to work now. I suspect that you are correct thought @Arne in that activating the correct virtual environment was the key, so I will mark that as the answer. Thanks you.

Comment: glad to hear you got it sorted out. Just in case anyone else runs into this issue, [the settings page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference) of vscode/pyhton covers most of the things you can set up that should solve problems around finding the right interpreter or script-entrypoint location.