# How to use IDE variables in launch.json in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Im using a virtual environment for my python project and I'd like to configure commands to automatize debugging.

So far, I've changed the `python.pythonPath` in `launch.json` and my intention is to update all dependencies before building with a custom task, which structure follows like

```js
{
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "tasks": [{
       "label": "echotest",
       "command": "python ...", // Could be any other shell command
       "args": ["test"],
       "type": "shell"
   }]
}
```

So, my question is if there is any way of using the `pythonPath` variable defined in `launch.json` inside the `command` key

Answer (score 0):

My question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56067344/13758294) in case it helps anyone. My final `tasks.json` is

```js
{
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "tasks": [{
       "label": "update dependencies",
       "command": "${workspaceFolder}\\${config:python.pythonPath} -m pip -r ${workspaceFolder}\\requirements.txt",
       "args": [],
       "type": "shell"
   }]
}
```

Care with blank spaces in folder names since scaping them with `\"`doesn't work at all